# How do I automate population of known_hosts and authorized_keys?

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, key-management

This is a question that may be easier answered on askubuntu or, perhaps, serverfault, but it arises in the context of automated provisioning, so I figured that it's more appropriate here.

I am spinning up a multi-machine environment in vagrant, e.g. `n+1` ubuntu-18.04 boxes, namely

- term (short for terminal)
- node1
- ...
- nodeN

They can all resolve each other by the above hostnames. It's necessary, that `term` can SSH into each of the nodes using its public key.

Manually I can do this with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

head='node'

ssh-keygen -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa

for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do
  name=$head
  name+=$i
  ssh-copy-id $name
done
```

running, e.g., `./copyid.sh 3`. But then I have to type `yes` (to confirm the fingerprint of the node) and `vagrant` (the password) three times.

I want to move this procedure to the provisioning of the VMs in the Vagrantfile. So I have two questions:

- How can this be automated without demanding manual input from myself?
- When I transfer over from virtual machines to bare metal servers, what best practices should I follow to prevent infosec guys from screaming "man in the middle" at me?

Comment: This probably could help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126908/get-ssh-server-key-fingerprint (running a keyscan on each host to add to your `term`'s known_hosts before doing the ssh-copy-id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute `ssh-keyscan`. For example to ssh to a host (github.com here ) you have to run below script

```
# Add ssh key to help cloning private github repo

ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f secrets/ssh/github_rsa
PUB_KEY=$(cat secrets/ssh/github_rsa.pub)
PRV_KEY=$(cat secrets/ssh/github_rsa)

echo "${PRV_KEY}" >> ~/.ssh/github_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/github_rsa
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa

ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
echo IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa >> ~/.ssh/config

echo "Paste the following public key to your host machine ".${PUB_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. A question, though. What (or rather, why) is being done in lines `eval...` thru `echo IdentityFile...` when it would seem that `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` is sufficient?

Comment: The default ssh keys stored in id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Note the name 'id_rsa'.  if you want to store those keys other than default name then you have to tell it to your ssh_agent. Though ssh-keyscan works in your case, I just gave a complete example incase you want to do the same from a CI server where you have to manually start ssh agent etc. However if that works don't forget to mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: Well, since noone else chimed in, I guess, I can accept this one. Thanks again!